# Adjust volume of both input mp3 files while merging using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, mp3, volume

I am using the following command to merge two audio files (mp3) into one output.mp3

```
-i /sdcard/NNR/input1.mp3 -i /sdcard/NNR/input2.mp3 
    -filter_complex amerge -ac 2 -c:a libmp3lame 
    -q:a 4 /sdcard/NNR/output.mp3
```

Kindly suggest me how to adjust volume level of both input files to some specific level.

I have found the following filter variable but don't exactly know how to adjust into my command.

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -i b.mp3 
   -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=.25[A];[1:a][A]amerge[out]" 
   -map [out] -c:a pcm_s16le out.wav
```

Any help will be much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use

```
-i /sdcard/NNR/input1.mp3 -i /sdcard/NNR/input2.mp3
-filter_complex "[0]volume=0.5,pan=2c[a];[1]volume=0.7,pan=2c[b];[a][b]amix=duration=shortest"
-ac 2 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 /sdcard/NNR/output.mp3
```

Comment: Hi Mulvya, i tried the way you suggested but its giving errors. I am now trying to set the volume via this command please check why i am not still able to execute command `ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.3;[1:a]volume=0.5;[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mp3`

Comment: What errors did you get with my command? Show console output.

Comment: `[Parsed_amerge_2 @ 0x7f9a90426860] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_2 @ 0x7f9a90426860] No channel layout for input 2
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f9a90416e00] The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_amerge_2
Consider inserting the (a)format filter near their input or output.
Error configuring complex filters.
Input/output error`

Comment: And my command is `ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1.0[A];[1:a]volume=.25[B];[A][B]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout]" -map "[aout]" output.mp3`

Comment: with this command I am not getting error but when i play output.mp3 the volume is almost zero because i cannot hear it all. Kindly check. Also please tell me what is max and min level of volume. `ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]volume=0.5,pan=2c[a];[1]volume=0.7,pan=2c[b];[a][b]amerge" -ac 2 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3`

Comment: You will have to experiment with the volume values. You can supply decibel if you like `volume=-6dB`

Comment: This edit of your command is giving me volume of first mp3 but not second mp3. can you please have a look? Thanks  `ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]volume=5.0[a];[1]volume=2.0,pan=2c[b];[a][b]amerge" -ac 2 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.mp3`

Comment: Use amix instead of amerge

Comment: amix is working. can i make the final recording to shortest length of input files ? Thanks a lot you did a great help. when i use amerge it automatically choose shortest and make final to length of shortest but in case of amix its making longest file length for output file.

Comment: Thankyou so much, you are a champ !

Comment: Just to know one more thing when we merge the audio quality remains the same of did it affect it ?

Comment: Depends on bitrate. Default is 128k, which is fine. You can use higher: `-b:a 192k`

Comment: @Mulvya, Only timeline is moving. No sound is there when i mergeed two audio using that cmd ```ffmpeg -i single-audio.mp3 -i racer.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]volume=0.5,pan=2c[a];[1]volume=0.7,pan=2c[b];[a][b]amix=duration=shortest" -ac 2 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 out.mp3```